# function with array.join -help in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

so before anything my experience with JavaScript is not that much, I'm trying to make a function called hashtag_it with an array and i want to add # before every index in this array so when I call the function the output is going to be #programming,#code , i tried to use array.join method but it didn't really work

```js
function hashtag_it(my_array) {
  my_array = ['programming','code']; 
  console.log(my_array.join('#'))
} 
console.log(hashtag_it());
```

Comment: Just think a little harder about the join, you want `,#` between each element, and then you'll need a `#` before the first, so just `'#' + my_array.join(',#')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const my_array = ['programming','code']; 
function hashtag_it() { 
   return my_array.map(item => `#${item}`).join(','); 
}
console.log(hashtag_it(my_array));
```

`.join` only joins by a separator after each element. You want to add `#` before each element. What I have changed is I have added `map` which simply appends `#` before each element and then you can use `join(',')` which joins each element using a `,` as a separator

References:

- [join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)
- [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

Comment: "Try this" is never a good explanation. Could you add some more details to your answer to _explain_ how you solved the problem?

Comment: Good point, added

Comment: hashtag_it doesn't return anything, yet you're console.logging its return value?

Comment: I directly modified the code in the original post, although that's not a good reason to keep it, thank you noting it @SuperStormer

Comment: I helped you a bit on formatting your answer... ;)

Comment: Thanks, looks much better!

Comment: About question/answer [formatting on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help), here is a useful page to bookmark ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `#` to all the elements in the array and then join it. Simply using join won't add `#` to the first element.

```js
function hashtag_it(my_array) {
  my_array = ['programming', 'code'];
  new_array = my_array.map(el => "#" + el).join(",")
  return new_array
}
console.log(hashtag_it());
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
const array = ["programming", "coding", "dogs"];

const tagIt = (arr) => {
  return arr.map(word => '#'+word).join(",");
};

console.log( tagIt(array) );
```

Comment: No explanation at all?

Comment: the code is self-explanitory